# Bot Framework : Error while creating a csv file in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, csv, botframework

I'm developing a chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework with Node Js.

My purpose is to send the user a csv file while he asks me something. 
I've implemented the following function but while I download the file 'prova.csv' the format is not recognized.

Inspecting well the format in output is of the type: *"data"* 
Anyone can help me what's wrong? Thanks

```
 function (session, results, next) {
    if (results.response.entity === 'Si') {
        const contentType = 'text/csv';
        const response = session.dialogData.far_ric_formato.response.rows;
        const csv = response.map(ric => `${ric.num};${ric.pin}`).join('\n');
        session.send({
            text: 'Ecco il CSV pronto per il download (MOCK)',
            attachments: [
                {
                    contentType: contentType,
                    contentUrl: `data:${contentType};base64,${Buffer.from(csv).toString('base64')}`,
                    name: 'prova.csv'
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 string of a .csv file can't be directly rendered on client side, as a workaround you can for example code like this:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var fs = require('fs');

bot.dialog('download', (session, result)=>{
    fs.readFile('./files/test.csv', function(err, data){
        var contentType = 'text/csv';
        var base64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');

        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
         .addAttachment({
            contentUrl: 'http://localhost:3978/csv/'+base64, //replace with your server url + base64 string.
            contentType: contentType,
            name: 'MyTest.csv',
         });
        session.send(msg);
    });
}).triggerAction({matches:/^download/i});

server.get('/csv/:base64code', (req, res, next)=>{
    let base64code = req.params.base64code;
    res.header('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename=test.csv');
    res.header('Content-type', 'application/csv');
    res.send(Buffer.from(base64code, 'base64'));
});
```

When user trigger the `download` dialog, it will send this file as attachment and when user click on this file, this .csv file will be downloaded in user's client side.